# How make this controller working properly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in rails and programming.

I have problem with my  ads_controller.rb, one params[:category] choose ads by category, and params[:search] choose category by search.

How to join this togheter, to make it works ?

```
def index

  if params[:category].blank?
   @ads = Ad.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  else
   @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
   @ads = Ad.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page]) 
  end

  if params[:search]
   @ads = Ad.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  else
   @ads = Ad.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is terribly confusing. Furthermore, what you are asking would be easy to accomplish with basic Ruby and Rails skills. I encourage you to read some book about the language and the framework before proceeding into using it.

Here's a possible solution

```
@ads = Ad.order("created_at DESC")
@ads = @ads.joins(:category).where(categories: { name: params[:category] }) if params[:category].present?
@ads = @ads.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
@ads = @ads.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Comment: It's works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Yep a definitely need to read some. Do you recommends any specyfic book ?